# Не работает обработчик формы в PHPStorm

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

Привет всем
Не могу понять почему не передаются данные из формы в массив POST
Есть обработчик формы(**actionForm.php**)

```
<?php
if ($_POST['title']){
    echo "its work!";
}
else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

И сам файл с формой(**form.html**)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="actionForm.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <button name="enter" type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Но когда пытаюсь получить значения input'a в **actionForm.php**, то в массиве **$_POST** ничего нет...

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

выдает результат

```
Array(0){}
```

Используемая версия php 7.0

Скажите что я делаю не так?)

Comment: сервер, среда разработки? [(на случай phpstorm)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35712396/1216425)

Comment: LAMP, среда PHPStorm

Comment: добавил ссылку в коммент выше, ознакомьтесь там, с постом и со ссылкой в нем. хотя я так понимаю сервер вы не интегрированный в IDE пользуете

Comment: попробую это, как приду домой. Но блин не через PHPStorm должно же работать...

Comment: Всё разобрался почему не работало. Дело в том что PHPStorm делает вот такую ссылку `http://localhost:63342/mysite.com/index.html?_ijt=gql40egp493smosbkku8rgm6f4` но она не правильная, ссылка должна иметь вот такой вид: `mysite.com/index.html`. Кто знает как отключить, функцию в phpstorm что бы он создавал нормальную ссылку, а не подставлял кучу своих параметров?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у Вас по умолчанию, создаются две среды разработки, одна Ваша LAMP (mysite.com), вторая сам PHPStorm (localhost:port/projectfolder/). Хотите избавиться от этого, укажите в настройках проекта корректное имя домена. С готовым проектом делается так:

1. Открыли PHPStorm
2. File->New project from existing files
3. Далее выбираем папку проект
4. После чего указываем доменное имя, в Вашем случае mysite.com.

А вообще не понятно зачем это Вам, отредактировали файл, сами в браузере открыли что нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую вечером!

Answer (score 0):

Проект запускается штормом со своей настройкой сервера, он никак не пересекается с настройками XAMP или Open Server (это баг в шторме). При обработке _POST ошибка просто выкидывает 404 страницу обработчика, которая прекрасно открывается без инициализации суперглобальной переменной с этими же настройками в шторме, но без значений из массива.

Как пример: `http://localhost:63342/1/1.php` открывается одновременно и как 404, и как нормальный выведенный echo поток без значений $_POST.

Comment: Был зол из за убитого зря времени на шторм.